# Is "looking for the treasure" an adverbial phrase?

Tags: sentence-structure, adverbs

Is "looking for the treasure" an adverbial phrase?

> Some pirates spent their whole lives *looking for the treasure*.

Comment: I don't know what use it is to you to know whether the category "adverbial phrase" applies here. But consider *Some pirates spent their treasure **wisely***, where unquestionably the highlighted element is adverbial (modifying the verb ***spent***). But in *my* example, it's quite okay to discard the adverb completely, and still be left with a perfectly valid sentence. On the other hand, if you remove ***looking for the treasure*** from your example, what's left doesn't make sense, so there's obviously *some* syntactic difference involved here.

Answer (score 1):

"Looking for the treasure" is a participle complement of the verb "spend".

The verb "spend" (in this sense) takes both an object and a participle.  A reasonable ([computer generated](https://www.link.cs.cmu.edu/link/submit-sentence-4.html)) parsing of the sentence could be

```
                  +--------------Pg--------------+                     
                  +----------Op---------+        |                     
                  |      +------Dmc-----+        |       +-----Jp-----+
  +--Dmc-+---Sp---+      |      +---AN--+        +--MVp--+    +--D*u--+
  |      |        |      |      |       |        |       |    |       |
some pirates.n spent.v their whole.n lives.n looking.v for.p the treasure.n 

Constituent tree:

(S (NP Some pirates)
   (VP spent
       (NP their whole lives)
       (VP looking
           (PP for
               (NP the treasure)))))
```